# Word Cloud: Code shows no error but displaying wordcloud raises name error

Tags: python, crash, word-cloud

Here are all the installation and imports:

```
!pip install wordcloud
!pip install fileupload
!pip install ipywidgets
!jupyter nbextension install --py --user fileupload
!jupyter nbextension enable --py fileupload

import wordcloud
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display
import fileupload
import io
import sys
```

This is the uploader widget:

```
from IPython.display import display
import fileupload

uploader = fileupload.FileUploadWidget()

def _handle_upload(change):
    w = change['owner']
    with open(w.filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(w.data)
    print('Uploaded `{}` ({:.2f} kB)'.format(
        w.filename, len(w.data) / 2**10))

uploader.observe(_handle_upload, names='data')

display(uploader)
```

The Wordcloud program:

```
def calculate_frequencies(file_contents):
    # Here is a list of punctuations and uninteresting words you can use to process your text
    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    uninteresting_words = ["the", "a", "to", "if", "is", "it", "of", "and", "or", "an", "as", "i", "me", "my", \
    "we", "our", "ours", "you", "your", "yours", "he", "she", "him", "his", "her", "hers", "its", "they", "them", \
    "their", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that", "am", "are", "was", "were", "be", "been", "being", \
    "have", "has", "had", "do", "does", "did", "but", "at", "by", "with", "from", "here", "when", "where", "how", \
    "all", "any", "both", "each", "few", "more", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "too", "very", "can", "will", "just"]

    # LEARNER CODE START HERE
    non_punctuation_text=""
    for char in file_contents:
        if char not in punctuations:
            non_punctuation_text=non_punctuation_text+char
    words=non_punctuation_text.split()
    clean_words=[]
    frequencies={}

    for word in words:
        if word.isalpha():
            if word not in uninteresting_words:
                clean_words.append(word)
    for alpha_word in clean_words:
        if alpha_word not in frequencies:
            frequencies[alpha_word]=1
        else:
            frequencies[alpha_word]+=1
    #wordcloud
    cloud = wordcloud.WordCloud()
    cloud.generate_from_frequencies(frequencies)
    return cloud.to_array()
```

Display our wordcloud image:

```
myimage = calculate_frequencies(file_contents)
plt.imshow(myimage, interpolation = 'nearest')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Error message:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-fd0f708f372c> in <module>
      1 # Display your wordcloud image
      2 
----> 3 myimage = calculate_frequencies(file_contents)
      4 plt.imshow(myimage, interpolation = 'nearest')
      5 plt.axis('off')

NameError: name 'file_contents' is not defined
```

what part of `file_contents` parameter am I missing? Why it is not displaying wordcloud?
I tried uploading different `.txt` documents from `uploader` widget but none is helping.

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Most of the posted code is irrelevant to the error you cite.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a file/text as an input to the calculate_frequencies function.
[Here is an example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIJhT.png)

```
 myimage = calculate_frequencies("Humpty Dumpty is a character in
 an English nursery rhyme, probably originally a riddle and one of the
 best known in the English-speaking world. He is typically portrayed 
as an anthropomorphic egg, though he is not explicitly described 
as such. ")  
plt.imshow(myimage, interpolation = 'nearest') 
plt.axis('off') plt.show()
```

Just copy paste any random paragraph from a website, and then see the word cloud come alive. 
:)

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for your contribution. As is, your suggestion is helpful - as a Comment to the OP's question, but it's not considered a complete and self-contained Answer, as per SO guidelines. You can `edit` to add the exact code required to execute your suggestion, and to add relevant info from the link you provided, and as well as any context or additional explanations. Links are fine, but relevant info must also be embedded into your post, so the answer is valid even if the info on that page changes or the link becomes unavailable. Link-only & incomplete answers are subject to removal.

Answer (score 0):

> Step -1

```
!pip install wordcloud
!pip install fileupload
!pip install ipywidgets
!jupyter nbextension install --py --user fileupload
!jupyter nbextension enable --py fileupload

import wordcloud
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display
import fileupload
import io
import sys
```

Above code output here----->

```
Requirement already satisfied: wordcloud in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from wordcloud) (3.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.6.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from wordcloud) (1.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from wordcloud) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib->wordcloud) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib->wordcloud) (40.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fileupload in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: ipywidgets>=5.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from fileupload) (7.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: notebook>=4.2 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from fileupload) (5.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.2 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from fileupload) (4.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel>=4.5.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipywidgets>=5.1->fileupload) (5.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: widgetsnbextension~=3.4.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipywidgets>=5.1->fileupload) (3.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: nbformat>=4.2.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipywidgets>=5.1->fileupload) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3" in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipywidgets>=5.1->fileupload) (7.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado<7,>=4.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from notebook>=4.2->fileupload) (6.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=17 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from notebook>=4.2->fileupload) (18.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: prometheus-client in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from notebook>=4.2->fileupload) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core>=4.4.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from notebook>=4.2->fileupload) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from notebook>=4.2->fileupload) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: Send2Trash in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from notebook>=4.2->fileupload) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from notebook>=4.2->fileupload) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from notebook>=4.2->fileupload) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: terminado>=0.8.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from notebook>=4.2->fileupload) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=5.2.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from notebook>=4.2->fileupload) (5.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from traitlets>=4.2->fileupload) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from traitlets>=4.2->fileupload) (4.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets>=5.1->fileupload) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets>=5.1->fileupload) (40.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.10 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets>=5.1->fileupload) (0.13.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets>=5.1->fileupload) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt_toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets>=5.1->fileupload) (2.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets>=5.1->fileupload) (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets>=5.1->fileupload) (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets>=5.1->fileupload) (4.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jinja2->notebook>=4.2->fileupload) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: mistune>=0.8.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.2->fileupload) (0.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints>=0.2.2 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.2->fileupload) (0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.2->fileupload) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandocfilters>=1.4.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.2->fileupload) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: testpath in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.2->fileupload) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.2->fileupload) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jupyter-client>=5.2.0->notebook>=4.2->fileupload) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets>=5.1->fileupload) (19.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets>=5.1->fileupload) (0.14.11)
Requirement already satisfied: parso>=0.3.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jedi>=0.10->ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets>=5.1->fileupload) (0.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from prompt_toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets>=5.1->fileupload) (0.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pexpect->ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets>=5.1->fileupload) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert->notebook>=4.2->fileupload) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ipywidgets in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (7.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: widgetsnbextension~=3.4.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipywidgets) (3.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: nbformat>=4.2.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipywidgets) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel>=4.5.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipywidgets) (5.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.3.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipywidgets) (4.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3" in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipywidgets) (7.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: notebook>=4.4.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from widgetsnbextension~=3.4.0->ipywidgets) (5.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython_genutils in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter_core in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets) (5.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=4.2 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets) (6.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from traitlets>=4.3.1->ipywidgets) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from traitlets>=4.3.1->ipywidgets) (4.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets) (40.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.10 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets) (0.13.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt_toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets) (2.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets) (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets) (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets) (4.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.4.0->ipywidgets) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: prometheus-client in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.4.0->ipywidgets) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=17 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.4.0->ipywidgets) (18.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: terminado>=0.8.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.4.0->ipywidgets) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Send2Trash in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.4.0->ipywidgets) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.4.0->ipywidgets) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets) (19.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets) (0.14.11)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: parso>=0.3.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jedi>=0.10->ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets) (0.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from prompt_toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets) (0.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pexpect->ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jinja2->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.4.0->ipywidgets) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: mistune>=0.8.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.4.0->ipywidgets) (0.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints>=0.2.2 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.4.0->ipywidgets) (0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.4.0->ipywidgets) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandocfilters>=1.4.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.4.0->ipywidgets) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: testpath in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.4.0->ipywidgets) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.4.0->ipywidgets) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.4.0->ipywidgets) (0.5.1)
Installing /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fileupload/static -> fileupload
Up to date: /home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/nbextensions/fileupload/widget.js
Up to date: /home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/nbextensions/fileupload/extension.js
Up to date: /home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/nbextensions/fileupload/fileupload/widget.js
- Validating: OK

    To initialize this nbextension in the browser every time the notebook (or other app) loads:
    
          jupyter nbextension enable fileupload --user --py
    
Enabling notebook extension fileupload/extension...
      - Validating: OK
```

> step-2

**This is code  write in the cell**

## This is the uploader widget

```
def _upload():

    _upload_widget = fileupload.FileUploadWidget()

    def _cb(change):
        global file_contents
        decoded = io.StringIO(change['owner'].data.decode('utf-8'))
        filename = change['owner'].filename
        print('Uploaded `{}` ({:.2f} kB)'.format(
            filename, len(decoded.read()) / 2 **10))
        file_contents = decoded.getvalue()

    _upload_widget.observe(_cb, names='data')
    display(_upload_widget)

_upload()
```

> Step-3

*Note:-  be careful to uplod / browser the file*

First open Notepad and copy ,paste this  script on your computer:-

```
"Humpty Dumpty is a character in
 an English nursery rhyme, probably originally a riddle and one of the
 best known in the English-speaking world. He is typically portrayed 
as an anthropomorphic egg, though he is not explicitly described 
as such. "
```

**Then save the txt file with this extension like:-
*file extension Name*

```
file_contents.txt
```

**then upload in browser :-like this**

```
Uploaded `file_contents.txt` (0.25 kB)
```

> Step-4

***Then move forward like this code***

```
def calculate_frequencies(file_contents):
    
    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    uninteresting_words = ["the","for", "a", "to", "if", "is","not","on", "it", "of", "and", "or", "an", "as","in", "i", "me", "my", \
    "we", "our", "ours", "you", "your", "yours", "he", "she", "him", "his", "her", "hers", "its", "they", "them", \
    "their", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that", "am", "are", "was", "were", "be", "been", "being", \
    "have", "has", "had", "do", "does", "did", "but", "at", "by", "with", "from", "here", "when", "where", "how", \
    "all", "any", "both", "each", "few", "more", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "too", "very", "can", "will", "just","than"]
    new_content = ""
    
    frequencies = {}
    for ch in file_contents:
        if ch not in punctuations:
            new_content += ch
    temp_file = new_content.split(" ")
    while "" in temp_file:
        temp_file.remove("")
    for word in temp_file:
        if word.lower() not in uninteresting_words:
            if word in frequencies:
                frequencies[word] +=1
            else:
                frequencies[word] = 1
    
    #wordcloud
    cloud = wordcloud.WordCloud()
    cloud.generate_from_frequencies(frequencies)
    return cloud.to_array()
```

> Step-5

```
# Display your wordcloud image
myimage = calculate_frequencies(file_contents)
plt.imshow(myimage, interpolation = 'nearest')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

**Outputs like this  :-**

[image]